# Externalizing LocalizedResources from Custom Policy Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have implemented localization by below changes to the XXX_TrustFrameworkExtensions file.

Can this LocalizedResources be externalized? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<BuildingBlocks>
    <ContentDefinitions>
        <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
            <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
                <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en-US" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="en-US"/>
                <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="es-MX" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="es-MX"/>
            </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
        </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
    <Localization Enabled="true">
        <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en-US" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
            <SupportedLanguage>en-US</SupportedLanguage>
            <SupportedLanguage>es-MX</SupportedLanguage>
        </SupportedLanguages>
        <LocalizedResources Id="en-US">
            <LocalizedStrings>
                <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="logonIdentifier_email">#Email Address</LocalizedString>
                <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="password">#Password</LocalizedString>
                <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="email_pattern">^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;'^_`{}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$</LocalizedString>
                <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfInvalidPassword">#Your password is incorrect.</LocalizedString>
                <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">#We can't seem to find your account.</LocalizedString>
            </LocalizedStrings>
        </LocalizedResources>
        <LocalizedResources Id="es-MX">
            <LocalizedStrings>
                <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="logonIdentifier_email">#Correo electrónico</LocalizedString>
                <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="password">#Contraseña</LocalizedString>
                <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="email_pattern">^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;'^_`{}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$</LocalizedString>
                <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfInvalidPassword">#Su contraseña es incorrecta.</LocalizedString>
                <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">#Parece que no podemos encontrar su cuenta.</LocalizedString>
            </LocalizedStrings>
        </LocalizedResources>
    </Localization>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

Comment: There seems to be a Url attribute on LocalizedResourcesReference that you can specify, but the only documentation I can find on it is "Specify a search engine URL, for example “https://bing.com”", which doesn't sound like it'd allow pulling the data from a URL :\

Comment: Can we know what do you mean by `LocalizedResources be externalized`. ?

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity I mean, move to a separate file so that it can be managed separately. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use policy file inheritance to extract your localization configuration into a separate file.
See Inheritence model for Custom Policies: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview#inheritance-model)

Here's an overview of what the policy file inheritance should look like:

```
[`Base` Policy file] (Contains your existing BuildingBlocks/ContentDefinition elements)
  ^
  |
[`Localization` Policy file] (Contains only Localization-specific configuration)
  ^
  |
[`XXX_TrustFrameworkExtensions` Policy file] (The policy file that your Relying Party will reference)
```

You'll need to create a "Localization" policy file and make your current Policy file (`XXX_TrustFrameworkExtensions`) inherit from it.
The Localization policy file will then need to inherit from your Base policy file. If you don't have a Base policy file, you should create one and move your `<BuildingBlocks>` element into it.

You'll need to define a `<BuildingBlocks>` element in both your Base and Localization policy file.
In your Localization policy file, you can add all of the localization-specific settings that you need for the `<ContentDefinitions>` and `<Localization>` elements.
When the Relying Party tries to reference your main Policy file (`XXX_TrustFrameworkExtensions`), Azure B2C will merge the contents of the `<BuildingBlocks>` elements from both your Base and Localization policy files.

The Azure B2C Custom Policy Starter Pack has a good example of how to achieve this.
See: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/LocalAccounts

## Example

`Your-Base-Policy.xml`:

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy    
    ...
    PolicyId="Your-Base-Policy"
    ...>  
  <BuildingBlocks>      
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.signinemail">
        ...
      </ContentDefinition>
     ...
    </ContentDefinitions>
  </BuildingBlocks>
  ...
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

`Localization-Policy.xml`:

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy    
    ...
    PolicyId="Localization-Policy"
    ...>
  <BasePolicy>...
    <PolicyId>Your-Base-Policy</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <!-- Contains only localization specific elements-->
  <BuildingBlocks>  
    <ContentDefinitions>      
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.signinemail">     
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Append">
            ...          
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
    </ContentDefinition>
    <Localization Enabled="true">
        <LocalizedCollections>          
        ...
        </LocalizedCollections>
        <LocalizedStrings>
        ...
        </LocalizedStrings>
      </Localization>
    </ContentDefinitions>
  </BuildingBlocks>
  ...
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

`XXX_TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml`:

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy    
    ...
    PolicyId="XXX_TrustFrameworkExtensions"
    ...>
 <BasePolicy>...
    <PolicyId>Localization-Policy</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  ...
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Answer (score -1):

Currently Localized resources can't be moved to separate file/Externalized.